# Problem about stationary set

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I have a problem about stationary sets. I want to show $A=\{\alpha < \omega_1 : \alpha$  is limit and  $cof(\alpha)=\omega \}$ is stationary in $\omega_1$. 
I want to show that if $C$ is a club then $C \cap A \neq \emptyset$. how I should proceed? Thanks for you help!

Comment: Why do you need to specify the cofinality? It is superfluous.

Comment: It's true, I specify because this is the exercise.

Comment: From your def'n of $A$ it is clear that you are talking about club & stationary subsets of $\omega_1.$... In general if  $k$ is an uncountable cardinal and $\omega\leq l=|l|<$cf$(k)$  then $\{x\in k:$ cf$(x)=l\}$  is stationary in $k.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Of course, the proof is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint: let $\langle \alpha_n \mid n < \omega \rangle$ be a strictly increasing chain of ordinals in $C$ and consider $\alpha = \sup_{n<\omega}\alpha_n$.

Comment: Ok, then $cof(\alpha)=\omega$ thus $\alpha \in C \cap A$. Thanks for your help!